# Broadcast screen over wireless

Tags: video, dlna, television

With my Sony Xperia Z1, I can use NFC to "pair" it to Sony TVs to broadcast what is being displayed on my phone on the TV screen as well. I would like to do this however I don't have a Sony TV. Is it possible to use an app or set up streaming so I can view my screen on my TV? I have a typical "dumb" tv connected to a Western Digital Live Hub which can access the videos/media stored on my phone without issues (supports DLNA) over my wireless network.

Comment: Do you just want to feed it MultiMedia content (streaming videos, music, and photos to it)? Then you can look out for UPnP apps like [BubbleUPnP](http://www.appbrain.com/app/bubbleupnp-upnp-dlna/com.bubblesoft.android.bubbleupnp). If you're thinking of "mirroring your device's screen content", that will be hard to impossible with a "dumb TV", as it usually requires a HDMI connection.

Comment: @Izzy unfortunately I mean the latter. I could do this with my Arc as it had a HDMI cable which worked a treat. As the Z1 will wirelessly mirror to Xperia TVs I was wondering if it was possible but I'm thinking not. The Z1 has a DLNA server built-in so I can play media from it but not show videos on the phone and TV at the same time. My ultimate goal is I want to watch the game I'm playing on the TV screen.

Comment: I vaguely remember having seen some app claiming to do that, but I'm neither 100% sure nor do I remember which it was. Miracast, maybe: Take a look at [this GoogleFu](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+screen+mirror+to+tv+wirelessly)

Comment: Miracast works great on my Nexus 4, it's called "Wireless Display" in Android 4.2 and 4.3. You need a Miracast receiver for your TV - some come with them built-in, some need an external unit. I use a Netgear PTV2000-100NAS "Push2TV" unit.

Comment: Sony sell a Miracast device for £79.99. That's high. It appears that my WDTV Live does not support Miracast so I will have to look at cheaper Miracast devices.

Comment: it appears in a recent firmware update the WDTV now support Micracast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll go ahead and post this as an answer. Android 4.2, including Sony's package on the Z1, supports [Miracast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miracast) - a wireless display standard that's sorta becoming a thing now. Miracast is what Sony uses to connect you to their own TV's, so it's not a proprietary Sony thing (surprisingly).

In order to use Miracast, you need either a Smart TV with the feature built in. Or you can use a Miracast Receiver - they range from $50-$80. I personally use [this one](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833122453) - it's worked great for me from Android and Windows without any hiccups.

Note that there is real latency between the phone and the TV's displays. You're looking at a 500ms lag at best, so this won't work well (or at all) for games. It's really good for watching videos, and things that don't require much interaction.

Comment: it appears in a recent firmware update the WDTV now support Micracast. There is some small lag, but not really noticeable.